# What is Social Cover in case of disease in France?

Tags: schengen, paperwork

I am traveling to France on Short Stay visa for two months from India. However apart from my other documents like Convention De Stage & Health Insurance, it was also suggested to submit a Social Cover in case of disease too. I am not sure what that is and neither do anyone I've asked in my organization.

My HR personnel from Paris office informed me about the insurances.
One is an insurance of 30000 euros which takes part in case of emergency(medical evacuation, repatriation to home country etc which is already done.
And the second one required is **a social cover, in case a disease** and this needs to be taken care from office in India. However nobody looks to be aware of it.

Comment: I'm not finding any references to this; could you please edit into the body of your question _exactly_ what was recommended, who recommended it, and in what context?